# Laravel google verification

Tags: laravel

Google asks me to verify my website by clicking link `www.domain.com/dummy_text.html`, but whenever i click this link I get `NotFoundHttpException` error. How can I reach files in public folder and avoid this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Just put the verification HTML file in the `public` directory.

Comment: I did. I bet laravel looking for route not file.

Comment: Unless you've done something weird in your server setup, files in `public` will override Laravel if they exist (otherwise your CSS/JS wouldn't function). You can also just make a route that serves the contents of the verification file, I suppose.

Comment: Strange. I did nothing unique with configurations. I will use your advise and will create new route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google verification HTML file can be copied directly to your public folder

Copy your google*************.html file to the public folder

and you can directly access it as follows

```
https://www.yourwebsite.com/google*************.html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|robots|google5959595959\.html)
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z-:._/\x7f-\xff]*)$ /public/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Ayman, thank you for contributing. It is better to provide some context for your answer instead of just lines of code. Thank you.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25720981)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to go to Google Search Console create an instance of the site to be verified.
After doing that, you do the following.

1) Upload the downloaded Google verification File to your public directory.

2) Assuming the Google Verification file's name is "google97ce02dabcfc3bb5.html", 
Edit your site's .htaccess file with the following configuration.

```
#Start of Google Analytics verification for Laravel
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|robots|google97ce02dabcfc3bb5\.html) 

RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z-:._/\x7f-\xff]*)$ /public/index.php/$1 [L]
#End of Google Analytics Verification for Laravel
```